# Create a List for each element of a List dynamically in JAVA

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am in a project where i should present a list of elements to the client and, after the client chooses one element of the list, I show the client another list of elements linked to his choice.

I used an arrayList for the first group of elements, and i should preferably use an hashMap for the other linked list.

I really don't know were to start from, or maybe i can use another data structure.

Thank you a lot

Here i post the code of "New's" class. Actually i am working server side, i present a list of news to the client and agter he choose the number of news he wants to read, i show all comments associated to that specific news.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class News
{
    private String journalist;
    private String title;
    FileManager fm = new FileManager("NewsList.txt");
    String PCPath = fm.getPCPath();

    private ArrayList<String> newsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void printNewsList()
    {
        setListLenght(newsList.size());

        // print all news
        for (int i = 0; i < elencoNotizie.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(newsList.get(i));
        }
    }

    /*
     * THE FOLLOWING METHOD ADDS NEWS FROM CLIENT INPUT -- EACH ELEMENT OF THIS LIST
     * SHOULD HAVE A LIST OF ITS COMMENTS (String) AND ITS VALUTATION (int) , THAT'S
     * WHY I'D NEED AN HASHMAP. EVERY TIME THE CLIENT ADDS A NEWS I SHOULD
     * DYNAMICALLY INCREAS THE HASM MAP DIMENSION TO INSTANTIATE A POSSIBILE LIST OF
     * COMMENTS FOR THAT NEWS
     */

    public void addNews(String receivedJournalis, String receivedTitle) throws IOException
            {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(PCPAth+"NewsList.txt", true);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                //save input in .txt file
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write((newsList.size()+1)+") Journalist: "+receivedJournalis+" - Title: "+receivedTitle);
                bw.close(); 

                   //save input in list
                newsList.add((newsList.size()+1)+") Journalist : "+receivedJournalis+" - Title: "+receivedTitle);

                //print all news list
                System.out.println(newsList.toString());
            }
```

Comment: If your elements are `int`s, then you could use a `Map<int, List<int>>`. The first group is the list of the map's keys, and the second is a lookup into the map given the selected item.

Comment: Can you please post your attempt.